# Series of digits in a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Given a certain number $\mathcal{N}$ with infinite digits, for instance $\pi$ or $\sqrt2$, it's possible to know if this number has a L-string of repeated numbers, but without actually computing the whole number $\mathcal{N}$?

To be concrete, take $\mathcal{N}=\sqrt2$. For instance I want to know if there is at least a sequence with $L=7$ times the number 3 (if yes, this means that $\sqrt2=1,41 \dots 3333333 \dots$), but without computing the infinite digits of $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no.

However,
for a "naturally" occurring
number,
like those you show,
everyone would be willing
to bet yes,
since it has been shown
that almost all numbers
are normal to every base.

Comment: For a "naturally occurring" **irrational** number, that is.  A **rational** number  has an eventually periodic decimal expansion, so in this case after a certain computable point any string of $L$ digits that hasn't shown up  yet never will.

Comment: I guess "naturally occurring" shouldn't include such things as $\theta_3(0, 1/10)$ where $\theta_3$ is a Jacobi theta function.